# Display question's answers and responses out of an exam

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models:

```rb
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exam_questions,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :question_responses
  has_many :questions, through: :exam_questions

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :question_responses
  has_many :exams, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :answers,  dependent: :destroy
end

class QuestionResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

Each `exam` is created once for each `user`. That means that each exam is unique. However, two different exams can have the same questions. For instance, suppose that I have 10 questions (q1, q2, ... q10). Exam 1 can have (q1, q2, q3, q4) and Exam 2 can have (q3, q4, q5, q6).

`QuestionResponse` is the response of an user when he/she is doing an exam.

I want to be able to save the user's question_responses and if the user answers only half of the exam and restart it another day, he/she will have displayed the questions not answered and also the ones answered.

Hence, I have this:

**exams_controller.rb**

```rb
 def show
    @exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
    @questions = @exam.questions
 end
```

**exams/show.html.erb**

```html
<!--//TODO: Too much logic here}-->
<section class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <% i = 1  %>
    <% @questions.find_each do |q| %>
      Question <%= i %>
      <% if !q.question_responses.where("question_responses.user_id = ?", current_user.id).present? %>
        <div class=" text-left word-break">
          <h2><b><%= q.description %></b></h2>
        </div>
        <%= image_tag q.image.url(:medium) if !q.image.blank? %>
        <div class="text-left">
          <% q.answers.randomize_answers.each do |a| %>
            <p class="answers" onclick="questionResponse(<%= @exam.id %>,<%= q.id %>, <%= a.id %>)">
              <%= a.description %>
            </p>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <% q.question_responses.where("question_responses.user_id = ?", current_user.id).find_each do |qr| %>
          <div class=" text-left word-break">
            <% question = qr.question %>
            <h2><b><%= question.description %></b></h2>
          </div>
          <%= image_tag question.image.url(:medium) if !question.image.blank? %>
          <div class="text-left">
            <% question.answers.randomize_answers.each do |a| %>
              <% if qr.answer.eql?(a) %>
                <p class="selected-answers" onclick="questionResponse(<%= @exam.id %>,<%= question.id %>, <%= a.id %>)">
                  <%= a.description %>
                </p>
              <% else %>
                <p class="answers" onclick="questionResponse(<%= @exam.id %>,<%= question.id %>, <%= a.id %>)">
                  <%= a.description %>
                </p>
              <% end %>
            <% end  %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <% i+=1 %>
    <% end  %>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically what I'm doing is getting all the questions in an exam and checking if it has `question_responses`. If not, I display the question's answers with class `answers`. If yes, I get the `question_responses`' answer and display it with class `answers-selected`.

This is working, but I think that the logic is not good at all. Should I change the relationship between the tables? Should I code a better query in the controller?

**EDIT:**

Here is my `Answer` model:

```rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :question_responses
  scope :randomize_answers, ->{order('random()')}
end
```

To make it a bit more clear: An user creates questions that are going to the questions bank. Another user creates an exam for itself. When an exam is created, `exam_questions` is populated:

**exams_controller.rb**

```rb
def create
    @new_exam = current_user.exams.new(exam_params)
    @new_exam.save!
    ExamQuestion.create_exam_questions(@new_exam.id, @new_exam.category, 3)
    if @new_exam.save!
      redirect_to exams_path
      flash[:notice] = "You've successfully created a new exam!"
    end
end
```

**exam_question.rb**

```rb
class ExamQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question

  def self.create_exam_questions(exam_id, category, n_questions)
    random_questions = Question.where(category: category).random_records(n_questions)
    random_questions.each do |rq|
      ExamQuestion.create(exam_id: exam_id, question_id: rq.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if two of a User's Exams have the same Questions? Should they have one QuestionResponse or two? That is, is a QuestionResponse per *Exam* or per *User*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make some schema changes.

You have Exams, Questions, and QuestionResponses all belonging to User. This allows for contradictions. You could have a QuestionResponse with a different User than its Exam. Questions belong to many Exams, they shouldn't have a User at all, unless it's the User who wrote the question? Instead, Exam should belong to User and the QuestionResponses should get its User through its Exam.

I'd also change QuestionResponse to directly reference ExamQuestions rather than redundantly storing the exam and question. This avoids the possibility of having a QuestionResponse to a Question which is not on the Exam.

This brings up a design question: what if a User has two Exams with the same Question on each? Do they get one QuestionResponse for both Exams? Or a QuestionResponse per Exam? That is, do they have to reanswer the same question on both exams?

I'd add some unique constraints to validate some assumptions.

- One QuestionResponse per ExamQuestion.
- One ExamQuestion per Exam and Question.

```
class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exam_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :question_responses, through: :exam_questions
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :exams, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :question_responses, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class ExamQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :question_responses
  has_one :user, through: :exam
end

class QuestionResponse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :exam_question
  has_one :question, through: :exam_question
  belongs_to :answer
  has_one :exam, through: :exam_question
  has_one :user, through: :exam
end
```

---

```
q.question_responses.where("question_responses.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
```

This seems incorrect. It will find all the User's responses to the Question in any Exam. But this is the show page for a single Exam, shouldn't it show only the User's responses to this exam?

Push the logic for this into the Question model.

```
  has_many :question_responses, through: :exam_questions do
    def find_by_user(user)
      joins(:exam).where("exams.user_id": user.id)
    end
  end

  def response_for_exam(exam)
    question_responses.joins(:exam).find_by("exams.id": exam.id)
  end
```

Now your view becomes simpler. Something like this.

```
<%= @questions.find_each.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
  Question <%= i + 1 %>

  <%=
    response = question.response_for_exam(@exam)
    if response
      render partial: "question_with_response", locals: {question: question, response: response}
    else
      render partial: "question_without_response", locals: {question: question}
    end
  %>
end
```

The use of [view partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) reduces how much code is in one view. [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) takes care of counting the questions for us.

Note that this is an 1+N query: we query the questions and then for each question query their responses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your `Answer` model, but let's assume it looks like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
#
#  id                   :bigint           not null, primary key
#  question_response_id :bigint
#  created_at           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at           :datetime         not null
#

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question_response
end
```

And let's assume your `QuestionResponse` looks more like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: question_responses
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  exam_question_id :bigint
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#

class QuestionResponse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :exam_question
  has_one     :answer

  class << self

    def with_answer
      joins(:answer).where(answer: Answer.all)
    end

  end
end
```

Now, let's assume your `ExamQuestion` (from your prior question) looks something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: exam_questions
#
#  id          :bigint           not null, primary key
#  exam_id     :bigint
#  question_id :bigint
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class ExamQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
  has_one    :question_response

  class << self 

    def for_question_responses(question_responses)
      joins(:question_response).where(question_response: question_responses)
    end

    def with_question_responses
      for_question_responses(QuestionResponse.with_answer)
    end

  end

end
```

And `Question` looks like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  user_id    :bigint
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :exams, through: :exam_questions

  class << self

    def with_answers
      joins(:exam_questions).
        where(exam_questions: {id: ExamQuestion.with_question_responses})
    end

  end
end
```

Finally, `Exam` might look something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: exams
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :exam_questions

  def questions_with_answer
    questions.with_answers
  end

  def questions_with_no_answer
    questions.
      where.
      not(id: questions_with_answer)
  end
end
```

Then, in your `exams_controller.rb`, you can do something like:

```
exams_controller.rb

def show
  @exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
  @exam_questions_with_answer = @exam.questions_with_answer
  @exam_questions_with_no_answer = @exam.questions_with_no_answer
end
```

Then, iterating through `@exam_questions_with_answer` and `@exam_questions_with_no_answer` in your view becomes trivial.

Naturally, I glossed over some of the details (like `q.answers.randomize_answers`), but I guess you get the idea.